# OS X API to mount a network volume

Tags: c++, macos, operating-system, afp

I'm trying to programmatically mount an AFP Volume in a most efficient way. Since `AFPMountURL` and the rest of AppleShareClient framework is deprecated, what is the current best way to mount network volumes on OS X?

I would like to avoid juggling with encoding complex usernames in URLs (i.e. `afp://user%40domain:pass@host...`, `smb://DOMAIN;user:pass@host/..` etc.) and get straight to the lowest level where I'd preferably be able to pass raw username, password, host and path directly to the system.